# I am getting weird results in MySQL query. Please help check what's wrong with it

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me get straight to the point. I have a query for which I should get results, but I am not getting results.

For this query, I should get results, but I don't get any results:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id=6944
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_candidate_location' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%London%')
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_candidate_title' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Entrepreneur%')
;
```

But if I do this I get results :

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id=6944
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_candidate_location' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%London%')
;
```

​

If I also do this I get results :

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id=6944
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_candidate_title' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Entrepreneur%')
;
```

​

Can someone please tell me why I am not getting results for the first query?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe its because of the double AND,  try changing the AND outside the parathesys to OR

Answer (score 2):

AND/OR issue I suspect

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id=6944
AND (
(wp_postmeta.meta_key='_candidate_location' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%London%')
OR (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_candidate_title' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Entrepreneur%')
)
;
```